# Why is the time parser not working in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

If you look at the line chart combo time scale [example](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/combo.html) (included at bottom) you'll notice that the time labels are printed as hourly markers over the previous 12 hours. This is despite the fact that the labels are explicitly set using:

```
var timeFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm';

function newDateString(days) {
    return moment().add(days, 'd').format(timeFormat);
}
```

And this time format is also applied in the configuration options:

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  display: true,
  time: {
    format: timeFormat,
    // round: 'day'
  }
}]
```

Why is this time format not being applied?

```js
var timeFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm';

function newDateString(days) {
  return moment().add(days, 'd').format(timeFormat);
}

var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      newDateString(0),
      newDateString(1),
      newDateString(2),
      newDateString(3),
      newDateString(4),
      newDateString(5),
      newDateString(6)
    ],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.green).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart.js Combo Time Scale'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        display: true,
        time: {
          format: timeFormat,
          // round: 'day'
        }
      }],
    },
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);

};

document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
  config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
      return randomScalingFactor();
    });
  });

  window.myLine.update();
});

var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var colorName = colorNames[config.data.datasets.length % colorNames.length];
  var newColor = window.chartColors[colorName];
  var newDataset = {
    label: 'Dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
    borderColor: newColor,
    backgroundColor: color(newColor).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    data: [],
  };

  for (var index = 0; index < config.data.labels.length; ++index) {
    newDataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
  }

  config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
  window.myLine.update();
});

document.getElementById('addData').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (config.data.datasets.length > 0) {
    config.data.labels.push(newDateString(config.data.labels.length));

    for (var index = 0; index < config.data.datasets.length; ++index) {
      config.data.datasets[index].data.push(randomScalingFactor());
    }

    window.myLine.update();
  }
});

document.getElementById('removeDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  config.data.datasets.splice(0, 1);
  window.myLine.update();
});

document.getElementById('removeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
  config.data.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

  config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, datasetIndex) {
    config.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data.pop();
  });

  window.myLine.update();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Line Chart - Combo Time Scale</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
 <style>
  canvas {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
 <button id="addDataset">Add Dataset</button>
 <button id="removeDataset">Remove Dataset</button>
 <button id="addData">Add Data</button>
 <button id="removeData">Remove Data</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Run the snippet full page vs not, and resize the browser window.  You'll get various outputs depending on the size and cropping.  You'll see that it is actually word wrapping and cropping.

Comment: When screen large it shows hourly ticks and when not it shows Aug 8, Aug 9, etc.  This is not the format specified: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'